# react js unable to retrive return data

Tags: reactjs

I use async/await to retrieve a json object and want to get one of the key's value, but it return as undefined.
Did I miss something in the code?

```
  const [registerResponse, setRegisterResponse] = useState({duplicateUser: false, 
         registration: false, username: ''})

  const submitHandler = async(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // console.log(newuser)
    const result = await fetch(API_URL,postOptions);
    setRegisterResponse(result.json())
    console.log(registerResponse)
  }
   console.log(registerResponse.duplicateUser)
```

I attached the output from developer tool
[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json

Comment: you have to await `result.json()` because it returns a promise : `setRegisterResponse(await result.json())`

Comment: And `console.log(registerResponse)` will still log the previous state due to the async nature of set state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
setRegisterResponse(await result.json())
```